# Connection refused when I am trying to get stream from IP Cam using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, protocols, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying to get the live feed from IP camera using opencv 4.0 python 3.7. I know the IP address of cam and admin and password. I have a camera of "Wifi Smart Camera" company and most probable the URL of camera is in format like this;

```
rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.20/live/ch00_0
```

here is the link where I see this info

https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Wifi+Smart+Net+Camera#

Here is my python code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open("rtsp://admin:admin123@192.168.4.18/live/ch00_0")

while(True):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here


    # Display the resulting frame
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    else:
        print("no frame occur")
        break

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

# When everything done, release the capture

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting this error

```
no frame occur
[tcp @ 0x558625a859c0] Connection to tcp://192.168.4.18:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
```

The interesting thing is when I add the port in URL just like below, no error occur but stream is also not extract

```
cap.open("rtsp://admin:admin123@192.168.4.18:8800/live/ch00_0")
```

One more thing is confusing me. When I access the IP cam using V380 Android App
I put admin, password and **Device ID** also. See this image.
[Android App Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQjg.jpg)
I see many stack questions, no one suggest to put Device ID in URL.

how can I access the stream of IP Cam using below information;

admin,
password, 
Cam IP add, 
Device ID.

Comment: The port IS important. And are you sure it is 8800? normally it is 554 for rtsp (different to the one used for html access)

Comment: @api55 No I am not sure about port, I just see the source code of app, when I see the java activity file of this, then I realize the hard core port '8800' and IP '190.168.1.1' with user credentials proceed further. I am not understand the whole code, I just guest the port. By the way I am trying port '554', but nothing solve it

Comment: your code have the wrong indentation after the `else:` is that correct, or just an error copying? The Connection Refused, means that the "computer" in that IP has no service listening in that port or the port is blocked. Some cameras tell you the port for rtsp on the settings under the network configuration tab. Maybe you should check it out. One more thing,  IP '190.168.1.1' is probably your router ip, do not use that one. You should use the camera IP.... Also this one `192.168.4.18` seems to be in another network than 190.168.1.1 (if mask is 255.255.255.0)

Comment: @api55 wrong indentation is in posted code not in actual code. I correct the code. IP of Cam is 192.168.0.146.

Comment: So that is the Ip you should use. Try "rtsp://admin:admin123@192.168.0.146:554/live/ch00_0" (change the password/user if needed.

Comment: @api55 got same error 'Connection refused'

Comment: It is hard to say what could be the problem. Usually it is the port/url... you can try to use wireshark and to see where the app connects to. Maybe is another port? maybe you can try to scan the camera ip for open ports. Try looking into the settings of the camera html interface, sometimes they let you configure the port there. Sorry, but that would be the most I can help you with, since I run out of ideas.